# How to parse users entered tags with php

Tags: php, parsing

I'm working on a custom CMS that has some built-in modules (calendar, weather, etc.) that we would like to allow end users to insert into their content. They can enter content using the CKEDITOR.

Looking for some tips on:

1. What is a recommended syntax for entering these codes? We need to retrieve module name and any relevant parameters. Was thinking something like: {{module-name, width=100, height=200, items=5}}
2. What PHP functions are best for parsing these?

I know there some templating libraries that may provide this type of functionality, but at this point we want to try to build this part ourselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick any syntax that will not find accidental use elsewhere in your project. Double curly brackets is probably fine.

Use a regular expression with non-greedy matching to grab the guts of each

```
$matches = array();
preg_match("/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/", $content, $matches);

// or use the match all the grab all of them
preg_match_all("/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/", $content, $matches);
```

from there, you can simply split them by comma and process the individual tokens

```
$tokens = split(",", $module);
$module_name = array_shift($tokens);
foreach ($tokens as $token) {
    // process the token
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. 

My rep is too low, but I'd up your reputation as so far you're the only that understood the questions.

Comment: No worries - I'm still building reputation too :) That being said, I love that stackoverflow is all about knowledge and helping each other and not about leveling up :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in way for parsing such (or similar) input. You will have to use some templating library or write a parser yourself.

Comment: Not sure why this response get rep points...it doesn't answer any of the questions or provide any useful feedback.